# How to set "args" from vimrc?

Tags: vim

I want to create a different lvimrc for my project that will set "args" to my source files.

Currently I do it during runtime by:

```
:argadd src/*.c inc/*.h
```

And I want to have that executed at startup. I always start vim from the root of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute commands automatically you can use autocommands (`:help autocmd`). If you're using an lvimrc, you could do

```
au VimEnter * argadd src/*.c inc/*.h
```

EDIT: Changed argsadd to argadd. That is the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

You could create an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or whatever:

```
alias lvim='vim +argadd\ src/*\ inc/*.h'
```

or add something like this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if ( getcwd() == '/path/to/project' )
  exec( 'argadd src/*.c inc/*.h' )
endif
```